# How to disable ChaCha20-Poly1305 encryption to stop the terrapin ssh attack

Tags: ssh, configuration, openssh

How to disable **ChaCha20-Poly1305** encryption from ssh under Debian?

I tried (as root):

```bash
echo 'Ciphers -chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com' > /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/anti-terrapin-attack
echo 'Ciphers -chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com' > /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/anti-terrapin-attack

systemctl restart sshd
```

But my `ssh -Q cipher` is still showing `chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com`.

**UPDATE:**

As the answers to fully solving my question are spreading across different answers, let me summarize them in one place.

- **Why? what's the fuss?** -- check out [Attack Discovered Against SSH](https://it.slashdot.org/story/23/12/20/1212226/attack-discovered-against-ssh), and Debian's `openssh` stable version is generations behind the official fix. Thus I need to fix it myself *now*.
- **Why OP is not working?** -- two points:

  - `ssh -Q` cipher always shows all of the ciphers compiled into the binary
  - all configuration files in the "`/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d`" directory should end with "`.conf`".
- **How to disable the attack?** -- See Floresta's practical solution https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/767135/374303
- **How to verify that the attack is disabled?** -- based on gogoud's practical solution:

```bash
nmap --script ssh2-enum-algos -sV -p 22 localhost | grep chacha20 | wc
      0       0       0
```

Better run it before and after applying Floresta's fixes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ssh -Q cipher` always shows all of the ciphers compiled into the binary, regardless of whether they are enabled or not.  This is true also for algorithms which are insecure or disabled by default.

The configuration you have set up should be sufficient to disable the algorithm, assuming you're using a recent version of OpenSSH which supports this syntax.  You can verify this by attempting to connect via `ssh -vvv`, which will print the server to client cipher list.

If you don't have a recent version of OpenSSH, then this syntax is not supported, and you need to explicitly list the ciphers you want.  The default is listed in `man sshd_config`, and, for my version of OpenSSH (Debian's 9.6), would look like this (without ChaCha):

```
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
```

Assuming you have modern clients, placing AES-GCM first in the list will improve performance (and security if you're not using encrypt-then-MAC), but there was an older version of OpenSSH which would segfault during rekeying with AES-GCM (which all major distros patched), which is why they're at the end of the list.

Note that if you're using a patched OS on both the client and server, then it's not necessary to disable `chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com`.  The reason is that authorized clients and servers will negotiate a secure connection with the `kex-strict-c-v00@openssh.com` and `kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com` extensions that are in patched versions of OpenSSH.  It doesn't matter what random scrapers do, because they'll drop off shortly thereafter and there's no need to protect them.

However, if you *aren't* using a patched OS, then of course you're vulnerable, but then again, you're vulnerable to a variety of other vulnerabilities as well.

Comment: hi! does one need to add `kex-strict-c-v00@openssh.com` to their KEX preferences in `sshd_config` explicitly?

Comment: No, you should not attempt to configure it; it's sent by the client automatically if it's supported, and I don't believe it works to try to set it explicitly.  You can see whether it's supported by using `ssh -vvv` when connecting to a client.

Comment: Ok thanks, you're kind to help! - and last question if I have say only `curve25519` set as my KEX preference (with nothing else listed), it will still send `kex-strict-c-v00@openssh.com` too to avoid Terrapin?

Comment: Yes.  `kex-strict-c-v00@openssh.com` is special in this regard just like the `ext-info-c`, which is used to negotiate extended capabilities.  They're always sent if the client supports them and they cannot be configured as key exchange methods because they aren't really key exchange methods.

Answer (score 5):

I think that your initial solution is partially correct.
On my Debian 12 box, the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` contains this line at the top:

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
```

So all configuration files in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d` directory should end with `.conf`. Same for the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d`.

The commands below work on my system:

```bash
echo 'Ciphers -chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com' > /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/anti-terrapin-attack.conf
echo 'Ciphers -chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com' > /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/anti-terrapin-attack.conf

systemctl restart sshd
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a practical solution and confirming that it is working. Still I'll accept bk2204's answer as s/he provides much more insight. Thank you all the same, +1.

Answer (score 3):

Try this as a way to check what ciphers are actually available for ssh (can also be run from a remote host):

```
nmap --script ssh2-enum-algos -sV -p 22 localhost
```

In my case, although `ssh -Q cipher` shows `chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com`, the above does not.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder, if `ssh -Q` is even supposed to reflect what's *configured*? The man page says it

> Queries ssh for the algorithms *supported* for the specified version 2.

If course it also can't verify the server-side configuration at all, since it doesn't actually connect anywhere.

I suppose you could try to connect somewhere with `ssh -v` and see what algorithm it ends up using:

```
$ ssh   -v $host 'true' |& grep -ie cipher
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
$ ssh  -o 'Ciphers -chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com'  -v $host 'true' |& grep -ie cipher
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com compression: none
```

Comment: Or `ssh -vv` shows _both_ proposals (local and peer) and you can just look at local e.g. `|& grep -A4 'local client'`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an embedded Linux device and it looks a bit different. On the device it reports having `chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com` compiled into the binary:

```
# ssh -Q cipher
3des-cbc
aes128-cbc
aes192-cbc
aes256-cbc
aes128-ctr
aes192-ctr
aes256-ctr
aes128-gcm@openssh.com
aes256-gcm@openssh.com
chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
```

I don't have `nmap` but running this from my PC works:

```
$ nmap --script ssh2-enum-algos -sV -p 22 192.168.1.62
Starting Nmap 7.94 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-02-09 18:00 NZDT
Nmap scan report for mydevice (192.168.1.62)
Host is up (0.17s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 8.9 (protocol 2.0)
| ssh2-enum-algos: 
|   kex_algorithms: (10)
|       curve25519-sha256
|       curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
|       ecdh-sha2-nistp256
|       ecdh-sha2-nistp384
|       ecdh-sha2-nistp521
|       sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com
|       diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
|       diffie-hellman-group16-sha512
|       diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
|       diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
|   server_host_key_algorithms: (4)
|       rsa-sha2-512
|       rsa-sha2-256
|       ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
|       ssh-ed25519
|   encryption_algorithms: (6)
|       chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
|       aes128-ctr
|       aes192-ctr
|       aes256-ctr
|       aes128-gcm@openssh.com
|       aes256-gcm@openssh.com
|   mac_algorithms: (10)
|       umac-64-etm@openssh.com
|       umac-128-etm@openssh.com
|       hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com
|       hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com
|       hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com
|       umac-64@openssh.com
|       umac-128@openssh.com
|       hmac-sha2-256
|       hmac-sha2-512
|       hmac-sha1
|   compression_algorithms: (2)
|       none
|_      zlib@openssh.com

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.55 seconds
```

However, I have two config files and no `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d` directory:

```
# ll /etc/ssh/sshd_config*
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        3.0K Mar  9  2018 /etc/ssh/sshd_config
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        3.1K Feb  9 05:17 /etc/ssh/sshd_config_readonly
```

I found appending `Ciphers -chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config_readonly` then restarting `sshd` worked for me:

```
echo '\nCiphers -chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config_readonly
systemctl restart system-sshd.slice
```

Now the `nmap` command above doesn't report `chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com`

Answer (score -1):

Add the following to /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
Ciphers -chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
```

Note the `-` at the start of the chacha20 cipher string.

Then restart your ssh server for it to take effect.

Comment: that does not work, that is the whole point of OP's question...